# ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice sends message to both success and fail channel in case of SpelException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I had asked few doubts in the comments section of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742953/how-to-move-files-using-expressionevaluatingrequesthandleradvice) thread.

While debugging the application I noticed some possible code errors. Are they bugs or features?

1. In `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice::evaluateSuccessExp‌​ression`, the exception is thrown after `AdviceMessage` is sent to `SuccessChannel`. This causes Exception payload in it. Shouldn't the method first throw the exception if there is one?
2. In the same class, `propagateOnSuccessEvaluationFailures` is 'false' by default which causes not to throw Exceptions. That rather negates purpose of `FailChannel`. I set it to 'true' externally. Can you please explain thought process behind these?

Gary has answered,

I don't understand your point 1. For point 2., generally, an error handler handles the error and there is no need for the caller to know there was a problem. If there is, then generally, the error handler flow should throw a new exception to indicate to the caller the error handler has been involved. The boolean is for the rare instance that you want to handle the error and also throw the original exception to the caller.

Instead of cluttering that thread, we can discuss the points in here.

I think the explanation for point 2 is applicable for `trapException`.

To make my point clear, I have copied part of `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

```
protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        try {
            Object e = callback.execute();
            if(this.onSuccessExpression != null) {
                this.evaluateSuccessExpression(message);
            }

            return e;
        } catch (Exception var7) {
            Exception actualException = this.unwrapExceptionIfNecessary(var7);
            if(this.onFailureExpression != null) {
                Object evalResult = this.evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
                if(this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
                    return evalResult;
                }
            }

            if(!this.trapException) {
                throw actualException;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void evaluateSuccessExpression(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        boolean evaluationFailed = false;

        Object evalResult;
        try {
            evalResult = this.onSuccessExpression.getValue(this.prepareEvaluationContextToUse((Exception)null), message);
        } catch (Exception var5) {
            evalResult = var5;
            evaluationFailed = true;
        }

        if(this.successChannel == null && this.successChannelName != null && this.getChannelResolver() != null) {
            this.successChannel = (MessageChannel)this.getChannelResolver().resolveDestination(this.successChannelName);
        }

        if(evalResult != null && this.successChannel != null) {
            AdviceMessage resultMessage = new AdviceMessage(evalResult, message);
            this.messagingTemplate.send(this.successChannel, resultMessage);
        }

        if(evaluationFailed && this.propagateOnSuccessEvaluationFailures) {
            throw (Exception)evalResult;
        }
    }

    private Object evaluateFailureExpression(Message<?> message, Exception exception) throws Exception {
        Object evalResult;
        try {
            evalResult = this.onFailureExpression.getValue(this.prepareEvaluationContextToUse(exception), message);
        } catch (Exception var6) {
            evalResult = var6;
            this.logger.error("Failure expression evaluation failed for " + message + ": " + var6.getMessage());
        }

        if(this.failureChannel == null && this.failureChannelName != null && this.getChannelResolver() != null) {
            this.failureChannel = (MessageChannel)this.getChannelResolver().resolveDestination(this.failureChannelName);
        }

        if(evalResult != null && this.failureChannel != null) {
            ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException messagingException = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException(message, "Handler Failed", this.unwrapThrowableIfNecessary(exception), evalResult);
            ErrorMessage resultMessage = new ErrorMessage(messagingException);
            this.messagingTemplate.send(this.failureChannel, resultMessage);
        }

        return evalResult;
    }
```

In `doInvoke`, `evaluateFailureExpression` is called if `callback.execute()` or `evaluateSuccessExpression` throws exception.

Now in `evaluateSuccessExpression`, if there is any error while evaluating `SuccessExpression`, the Exception is stored in `evalResult`. This is sent to `SuccessChannel` if it is configured. If `propagateOnSuccessEvaluationFailures` is set to `true` then only `evaluateSuccessExpression` throws error. As it is set to 'false' by default, `evalResult` is not thrown and consequently not caught by `evaluateFailureExpression`.

Even if `propagateOnSuccessEvaluationFailures` needs to be set to 'false' by other requirements, the check to throw exception should be before sending the result to `SuccessChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the point. 
Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and we will revise that block of logic. In general I agree that it would be better to check for rethrow first of all and only after that send that exception to the `successChannel`.

Unfortunately there is no workaround for this (unless your own solution) and we can't fix it immediately because it is going to be behavior changing - someone might really rely on this status quo.

I even think that we may to revise the default for the `propagateOnSuccessEvaluationFailures` since you have point here as well. But again: we can make it only in the next `5.1` version.

Comment: thank you for your comment. How can I raise JIRA issue?
I agree that it is a behavior change so needs time for review.